# PyGTK: Change combobox drop-down menu from a previous combobox drop-down menu

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am new in python and Pygtk and I do not know how to update a drop-down menu items from a previous drop-down menu items. I am trying to set the liststore of a combobox (cb2) that depends of the choice of a previous combobox (cb1). So I think this is a dynamic cb2 since it depends of the cb1 user choice.

The cb1 has items C1 and C2. If I choose C1, I want the cb2 items to be 2,3 and 4. If I choose C2, I want the cb2 items to be 2,3,4 and 6.

Can someone help me?

Here is the test case code I have so far. But the changes does not work!

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(type=gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

        self.vbox_setup = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.vbox_setup.set_border_width(10)
        self.window.add(self.vbox_setup)
        self.conf_1()

        self.window.show_all()
        gtk.main()

    def conf_1(self):
        self.obs_box = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.vbox_setup.pack_start(self.obs_box, False, True, 0)
        self.label = gtk.Label('Conf1')
        self.obs_box.pack_start(self.label, False, True, 3)
        self.label_lat = gtk.Label('Latitude: ?')
        self.combobox_1 = gtk.ComboBox()
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.combobox_1.pack_start(self.cell)
        self.combobox_1.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 0)
        self.obs_box.pack_start(self.combobox_1, False, True, 3)
        self.liststore.append(['Select:'])
        self.liststore.append(['C1'])
        self.liststore.append(['C2'])
        self.combobox_1.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.combobox_1.connect('changed', self.conf1_choice)
        self.combobox_1.connect('changed', self.conf2_choice)
        self.combobox_1.set_active(0)
        self.obs_box.pack_start(self.label_lat, False, True, 3)

    def conf1_choice(self, combobox):
        model = combobox.get_model()
        index = combobox.get_active()
        if model[index][0] == 'C1':
            self.latitude = -4.23
        elif model[index][0] == 'C2':
            self.latitude = 45.22
        else :
            self.latitude = 0
        lat_dgr = int(self.latitude)
        lat_mn = int((self.latitude %1)*60.)
        lat_s = ((self.latitude %1)*60. %1)*60.
        self.label_lat.set_label('Latitude: '+str(lat_dgr)+u'\u00B0 '+
                             str(lat_mn)+u'\u0027 '+str(round(lat_s,2))+u'\u0027\u0027' )

    def conf2_choice(self, widget):
        self.configuration_box = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.vbox_setup.pack_start(self.configuration_box, False, True, 0)
        self.label = gtk.Label('Configuration')
        self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.label, False, True, 3)
        self.combobox_2 = gtk.ComboBox()
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.combobox_2.pack_start(self.cell)
        self.combobox_2.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 0)
        self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_2, False, True, 3)
        self.liststore.append(['Select:'])
        model = self.combobox_1.get_model()
        index = self.combobox_1.get_active()
        if model[index][0] == 'C1':
            self.liststore.append(['2'])
            self.liststore.append(['3'])
            self.liststore.append(['4'])
        if model[index][0] == 'C2':
            self.liststore.append(['2'])
            self.liststore.append(['3'])
            self.liststore.append(['4'])
            self.liststore.append(['6'])
        self.combobox_2.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.combobox_2.set_active(0)
        self.combobox_2.connect('changed', self.conf3_choice)

    def conf3_choice(self, widget):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uv = test()
```

Additionally, I also want that the choice  cb1=C1 and cb2=2 create 2 other comboboxes with items T1,T2 and T3, or if I choose cb1=C1 and cb2=4, it will create 4 other comboboxes with items T1,T2 and T3. The same for cb1=C2 but with items U1,U2,U3 and U4.  In such case, my implementation of *conf3_choice* is:

```
def conf3_choice(self, widget):
    model_1 = self.combobox_1.get_model()
    index_1 = self.combobox_1.get_active()
    model_2 = self.combobox_2.get_model()
    index_2 = self.combobox_2.get_active()
    self.new_box_1 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox_setup.pack_start(self.new_box_1, False, True, 0)
    self.new_box_2 = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox_setup.pack_start(self.new_box_2, False, True, 0)
    self.combobox_3 = gtk.ComboBox()
    self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
    self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.combobox_3.pack_start(self.cell)
    self.combobox_3.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 0)
    self.liststore.append(['Select:'])
    if model_1[index][0]=='C1':
        self.liststore.append(['T1'])
        self.liststore.append(['T2'])
        self.liststore.append(['T3'])
        self.combobox_3.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.combobox_3.set_active(0)
        if model_2[index][0]=='2':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
        if model_2[index][0]=='3':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
        if model_2[index][0]=='4':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
    if model_1[index][0]=='C2':
        self.liststore.append(['U1'])
        self.liststore.append(['U2'])
        self.liststore.append(['U3'])
        self.liststore.append(['U4'])
        self.combobox_3.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.combobox_3.set_active(0)
        if model_2[index][0]=='2':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
        if model_2[index][0]=='3':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
        if model_2[index][0]=='4':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
        if model_2[index][0]=='6':
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
            self.configuration_box.pack_start(self.combobox_3, False, True, 3)
```

Comment: It is better to provide the minimal test case.  It is easier to read, easier to catch issues and it is more general (which would help other people as well).

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing the same model (self.liststore) with every combobox.  Similarly with self.cell.  You should use local variables for them, if you need them later, you can get with **get_model()**, etc.  Second, it does not sound like a good idea to create widgets every time a combobox changes; a better approach is create the widgets at the beginning and enable/disable them as needed.  In all cases, you only need to update the model (*liststore*).

I re-arrange a bit your code in order to put related functions together. By using local variables and the proper order, you will notice now the code works.  You can extrapolate the code here to make the 3rd and 4th combobox work.

At last but not least, it is necessary to **clear()** the model for the second combobox anytime you would like to add items.

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(type=gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

        self.vbox_setup = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.vbox_setup.set_border_width(10)
        self.window.add(self.vbox_setup)
        self.create_comboxbox()

        self.window.show_all()
        gtk.main()

    def create_comboxbox(self):
        # Main Combo box
        liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(['Select:'])
        liststore.append(['C1'])
        liststore.append(['C2'])

        self.obs_box = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        self.vbox_setup.pack_start(self.obs_box, False, True, 0)
        label = gtk.Label('Conf1')
        self.label_lat = gtk.Label('Latitude: ?')

        self.combobox_1 = gtk.ComboBox()
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.combobox_1.pack_start(cell)
        self.combobox_1.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
        self.combobox_1.set_model(liststore)
        self.combobox_1.set_active(0)
        self.combobox_1.connect('changed', self.conf1_choice)
        self.combobox_1.connect('changed', self.conf2_choice)

        self.obs_box.pack_start(label, False, True, 3)
        self.obs_box.pack_start(self.combobox_1, False, True, 3)
        self.obs_box.pack_start(self.label_lat, False, True, 3)

        # Secondary Combo box
        liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(['Select:'])

        label = gtk.Label('Configuration')
        self.combobox_2 = gtk.ComboBox()

        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.combobox_2.pack_start(cell)
        self.combobox_2.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
        self.combobox_2.set_model(liststore)
        self.combobox_2.set_active(0)
        #self.combobox_2.connect('changed', self.conf3_choice)

        self.obs_box.pack_start(label, False, True, 3)
        self.obs_box.pack_start(self.combobox_2, False, True, 3)

    def conf1_choice(self, combobox):
        model = combobox.get_model()
        index = combobox.get_active()
        if model[index][0] == 'C1':
            self.latitude = -4.23
        elif model[index][0] == 'C2':
            self.latitude = 45.22
        else:
            self.latitude = 0
        lat_dgr = int(self.latitude)
        lat_mn = int((self.latitude %1)*60.)
        lat_s = ((self.latitude %1)*60. %1)*60.
        self.label_lat.set_label('Latitude: '+str(lat_dgr)+u'\u00B0 '+
                             str(lat_mn)+u'\u0027 '+str(round(lat_s,2))+u'\u0027\u0027' )

    def conf2_choice(self, widget):
        model = self.combobox_1.get_model()
        index = self.combobox_1.get_active()
        liststore = self.combobox_2.get_model()
        liststore.clear()
        liststore.append(['Select:'])
        if model[index][0] == 'C1':
            liststore.append(['2'])
            liststore.append(['3'])
            liststore.append(['4'])
        if model[index][0] == 'C2':
            liststore.append(['2'])
            liststore.append(['3'])
            liststore.append(['4'])
            liststore.append(['6'])
        self.combobox_2.set_model(liststore)
        self.combobox_2.set_active(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uv = test()
```